# How do I get my disk space back from my deleted virtual machine from VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, disk-space

As a context, I wanted to upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04, but I don't have enough disk space.

After having deleted a virtual machine from VirtualBox, I didn't gain any disk space, which I found odd. Is it possible that my virtual machine, even if deleted, still occupies disk space? If so, how do I tell my computer this space is free to use again?

Comment: A VM is just a configuration file that connects the virtual hardware elements. You can delete a VM but keep it's virtual hard disk image. You can check in the "Virtual Media Manager" (menu "File" in VirtualBox Manager).

Comment: There's nothing in "Virtual Media Manager". I think my VM was using so little disk space, that when deleting it, I didn't notice the little space that was freed... In the end, I deleted 3.4 GB of log files to get enough disk space for my Ubuntu upgrade. Maybe I should remove this post.